# Checking if a mathematical transformation returns true on a Ruby range

Tags: ruby

say I have a Ruby range, `1..500`, and I'd like to ask the question of whether any element in that range is evenly divisible by 5.  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
(1..500).any?{|n| n%5 == 0 }
```

Thanks @nash for Ruby sugar:

```
(1..500).any?{|n| n.modulo(5).zero? }
```